# How to edit audio bitrate, speed and trim in FFmpeg with a single command?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to edit audio files with 3 parameters: I have to change the bitrate, speed and I have to trim the audio.

I tried filter complex to combine 3 commands into one commands but didn't worked.

What I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "-b:a 256k, atempo=2, -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:40" output.mp3
```

The error I get is:

```
No such filter: '-b:a 256k'
```

Is there any way to achieve this without using `&&` operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command works, although I am still not certain it does exactly what you need.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -b:a 256k -filter_complex "atempo=2" -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:40 output.mp3
```

Comment: Finally.... Thank you very much, it worked.